# Ranges of projection operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space and $P$ and $Q$ be bounded linear projections on $X$ such that $PQ$ and $QP$ are compact. Does it follow that $PQ$ and $QP$ are finite-rank operators?

My attempt: I claim that both $PQ$ and $QP$ have closed range so if the range of one of them were not finite-dimensional, we would find a bounded sequence in it without a convergent subsequence.

Is it fine? If so, can we find a projection $R$ with finite-dimensional range such that $PQ$ and $QP$ commute on the image of $I-R$?

Comment: @TomekKania Why don't you post your counterexample?

Comment: @Norbert, because it was a counterexample to your conclusion, no to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space. Let $\{E_{kj}\}$ be the canonical set of matrix units. Let 
$$
X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k\,E_{2k,2k+1}, \ \ \ E=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{2k,2k}
$$
and let $P=E+X$, $Q=I-E+X^*$. Note that $X^2=0$, $EX=X$, and $XE=0$, so 
$$
P^2=P, Q^2=Q.
$$
Also, 
$$
PQ=E(I-E)+EX^*+X(I-E)+XX^*=X+XX^*,
$$
$$
QP=(I-E)E+(I-E)X+X^*E+X^*X=X^*+X^*X.
$$
So both $PQ$ and $QP$ are compact, but not finite-rank.

It may help to see them as direct sums:
$$
P=0\oplus\bigoplus_{k=1}^\infty\begin{bmatrix}1&1/k\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ Q=1\oplus\bigoplus_{k=1}^\infty\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1/k&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
and then
$$
PQ=0\oplus\bigoplus_{k=1}^\infty \begin{bmatrix}1/k^2&1/k\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
QP=0\oplus\bigoplus_{k=1}^\infty \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1/k&1/k^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$